# Stored Procedure cannot run successfully in SQL Server via SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy, python-3.6

## What I am using

1. Ubuntu 16.04

   - Python 3.6
   - FreeTDS, TDS Version 7.3
   - SQLAlchemy 1.2.5
2. Windows server 2012

   - SQL Server 2008 Enterprise

## My purpose

I write code in Python on Ubuntu machine to insert and execute stored procedure on MS SQL Server 2008. I create an order for customer. An order may have many main ingredients, toppings. When finish order, I run a stored procedure to process data to `user_order` and `employee_order`.

## The stored procedure

In stored procedure, when select data from source tables and process data, if any error is happened, transaction is rolled back.

## My code snippet

```
def process():
    engine = get_engine() # my method get engine by connection string
    session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine.execution_options(isolation_level='SERIALIZABLE'))
    session = session_maker()
    ref = 'REF0000001'
    try:
        # Create order
        order = Order(id=1, ref=ref)

        # Add main ingredients
        main1 = Main(order=1, name='coffee')
        main2 = Main(order=1, name='milk')

        # Topup
        topup1 = TopUp(order=1, name='cookies')
        topup2 = TopUp(order=1, name='chocolate')

        session.add(order)
        session.flush()

        session.add_all([main1, main2])
        session.flush()

        session.add_all([topup1, topup2])
        session.flush()

        session.commit()
    except:
        session.rollback()
        reraise
    finally:
        session.close()
        del session

    time.sleep(1)
    session = session_maker()
    session.execute('EXEC finish_order %a' % ref)
    session.commit()
    session.close()
    del session
```

## And result is

There is no error, but there is no data in `user_order` and `employee_order` even though stored procedure `finish_order` is run.

But, if I run the stored procedure again as a simple query in terminal or SQL Studio Management, the data is imported to destination tables.

## Doubts

Is there any chance that data has not been finished inserting into origin tables yet when stored procedure is called?

Please help me with this case.

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, don't string format values to queries, even if it seems to work for your case. Instead let SQLA / DB-API driver replace placeholders: `session.execute('EXEC finish_order :ref', ref=ref)`. Since your error "handling" just catches everything and rolls back, compared to rollback and reraise, are you sure the part *before* calling the stored proc works? In other words your doubts may be correct in a way, but this is not a timing issue. After callung flush the changes held by the session will be written to the DB.

Comment: Hi @IljaEverilä, I added `reraise` but there is no error, too. In `finish_order` procedure, there are some code lines handling error and rollback. May it cause problem?